# opacity around the message

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to make a poup screen with high opacity around the popup screen in winform? If yes, how?

How do I make the pop up message or GUI screen to be in the middle of the computer screen?

Please remember that I don't have any source code yet.

An example:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about graying out (or darkening) the rest of the screen around the message? The effect commonly referred to as ["lightboxing"](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/592-been-lightboxed-lately) in web apps?

Comment: This effect should be reserved to the UAC prompt.  Simulating it only confuses your user and makes it unnecessarily difficult to use other programs.  Her next likely move is running your uninstaller.

Comment: While I tend to agree with Hans, I also appreciate that your customer may be requesting this feature. That's why I suggested you *only* gray out *your application's window*, rather than the entire screen. UAC darkens the entire screen and makes it difficult to use other apps. If you only gray out your *own* app, it's more clear to the user what's happening, and they can still switch to a different app. Don't do it unless you have to, but if you must, this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show your `Form` at center of screen, use `StartPosition` property of form to **CenterScreen**.

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

---

**Now, to grey rest of the portion of screen.**

Take a new `form` name it **frmBlur** and set these properties.

```
this.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;            
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;            
this.Opacity = 0.8;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;  
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

---

Now, use the below code to display MessageBox or winform

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (frmBlur ob = new frmBlur())
        {
            ob.Show();
            frmMessage f = new frmMessage();
            f.TopMost = true;
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't make it top-most, as that will prevent the user from interacting with *other* applications on their computer. Since the example is not a system modal dialog, it should only limit access to the rest of the application. The easiest way to do that is using the `ShowDialog` method (instead of `Show`) and setting the Z order appropriately.

Comment: "and setting the Z order appropriately". I dont understand this context?

Comment: You don't have to set the z order really. Just ShowDialog for the gray form; then (inside the gray form's OnShown) ShowDialog for the actual dialog box. If you want to make it look extra nice make the gray form take the exact shape and size of your main form that you're trying to hide.

Comment: @Fullmetalboy: Right, the Z order will automatically be set correctly if you show the forms in the correct order. You only need to manage it manually if you do things out of order. I just meant that your main form should be in the background, with the darkened transparent form on top of it, and finally your message box at the very top of the Z order.